# Application Gateway ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I believe I have configured Application Gateway correctly however I am getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
If I ping the url I get the IP address of the App Gateway back.

My back end is marked as healthly and also if I remote onto my box the app is up and running as expected.

I have successfully created a probe that uses the specific URL that Im using - this is marked as green.

I have an HTTP Listener (multi-site) listening on HTTP port 80 (as required) which is associated with a rule. The rule is associated with the green backend and httpsettings.

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Thanks!

Comment: Run `ipconfig /flushdns` in the CMD? try to clear the cache in the web browser or access it via private mode? Try to access that app gateway URL on another machine?

Answer (score 1):

Check for the following:

1. Make sure you are access the web site with FQDN, not with the IP address as it is a multi-site config
2. If you have any NSG on the Application Gateway, then make sure you open ports which Application gateway Listener is configured to.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the AGW was configured correctly - using Curl everything worked fine. My issue was elsewhere :)